# C# - calling another web api returned "null"

Tags: c#, asp.net

i just started to learn web api with aspnet. so basically i made 2 project with yeoman. lets say 1 project just returned string "hello" and the other project calling that hello and also returned string "World". the purpose of this is when i use get method on "world" project . it returned some string "hello world". i have installing those 2 projects in docker but it retured null.
you can check it in [here](http://188.166.236.181:5513/api/niko/hello)

so here the code project 2 have

```
 httpclienttest client = new httpclienttest(); //project 1 doesn't have this

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task< IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
      var hello = await  client.GetProductAsync("api/niko/hello"); //project 1 doesn't have this
      return new string[] { "Hello Niko calling service",hello};
    }
```

and here the method that called another service

```
 public class httpclienttest
{

    public string Hello ;
    public async Task<string> GetProductAsync(string path)
    {
         HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://188.166.236.181:5513");

        try 
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response =  client.GetAsync(path).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                Hello = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return Hello;
    }
```

iam so sorry for my bad explanation and thank you for your response

Comment: Use wireshark to see network traffic if there is connection. Use debug breakpoint if the controller is hit; What e.Message shows? Instead display whole exception so there should be an exception type. As the response is taking a lot of time, it looks like a TIMEOUT for me - so no connection with WebAPI controller.?

Comment: @LeszekRepie can you give me some example or some link i can follow? because i have no idea how to do that. thanks